# Function for first match in a nested array

Tags: apl

What is the best way to search a nested array like this for the first appearance of 2 2 2 in each vector? Are there special functions in APL to avoid searching the entire vector?

?10/¨10⍴2

(1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2)  (1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1)  (1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)  (1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2)  (1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1)  (1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)  (1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2)  (1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1)  (1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2) (1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1)

Index position for the first 2 2 2 or a 0 if not present for a 10 item array.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
    firsthit←{(⊃⍸)¨⍺∘⍷¨⍵} ⍝ (first where) each ⍺ found in each ⍵
    v←?10000/¨10000⍴2
    t←⎕AI[3] ⋄ ≢2 2 2 firsthit v ⋄ ⎕AI[3]-t 
10000
666
```

(666 milliseconds elapsed)

Comment: t←⎕AI[3] ⋄    z←firsthit1 ¨ ?10000/¨10000⍴2   ⋄  ⎕AI[3]-t
1055

Comment: both about the same - - - - -t←⎕AI[3] ⋄    z←2 2 2 firsthit2  ?10000/¨10000⍴2   ⋄  ⎕AI[3]-t
1148 ------------


                       t←⎕AI[3] ⋄    z←firsthit1 ¨ ?10000/¨10000⍴2   ⋄  ⎕AI[3]-t
1055

Seems very fast for 100,000,000 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the best way, but if each vector only has a small number of elements (less than a thousand), I doubt searching the whole vector is an issue.

Here's a dfn in Dyalog APL which returns the index of the first `2 2 2` in a vector, `0` otherwise.

```
{len←≢⍵⋄{⍵×⍵≢len+1}1⍳⍨2 2 2⍷⍵}
```

Turning it into a solution for your problem is as easy as sticking `¨` on the end to do it for all vectors.

Explanation:

`len←≢⍵⋄` notate the length of the vector with `len`

`2 2 2⍷⍵` Find all instances of `2 2 2`

`1⍳⍨` Get the first index of `1` (i.e the index where the first `2 2 2` starts) returning `len+1` if it's not found

`{⍵×⍵≢len+1}` Set to 0 if it's equal to `len+1`

Comment: Works good. Thanks. At the higher item count like you thought it could use a special form for "first" like J has I think which would speed things up. But I don't need the speed. I dabble in J and crawl in APL. ⎕TS ⋄    a← firsthit ¨   ?10000/¨10000⍴2  ⋄ ⎕TS
2018 6 8 13 35 30 516
2018 6 8 13 35 31 593